# SSH connection. no route to host

Tags: raspbian, ssh, ethernet

I'm trying to connect my rasberry pi through ethernet.
I'm using debian 8.9.0.

When i typ the command:
ssh -l pi 192.168.1.100

I get the following error ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.100 port 22: No route to host.

I'm very new to rasberry so i'm not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are running headless:**

1. Make sure that is the IP address for your Raspberry pi, can you ping 192.168.1.100.
2. Have you created a file called "ssh" without extension in /boot of the SD-Card?

**If you have a screen and keyboard connected**

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and choose advanced->enable ssh

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use a mobile stick for internet access and local router too. I played the router settings and setted some option, which need to ssh for me.

- separate AP [*on*] <- ***wrong*** setting in my case

And a many long months later I try ssh connect to my raspberry, but it exited with `No route to host` message. I find firewall settings, and sshd config, but everything looked good. After that I remember to the router settings, and try out revert some setting, and one of that works:

- separate AP [**off**] <- **good** setting in my case

I am not sure what is this setting doing, but I am sure, without this cannot connet via ssh or VNC to raspberry. The strange thing that rpi has internet access and works well, therefore, it has not been revealed before.